# Is the 'passport application locator number' the same as the passport number?

Tags: usa, passports

I am trying to book a flight on Sky Airline which is asking for my passport number in order to book the flight. Problem is that I do not have my passport yet, but https://passportstatus.state.gov states that I should receive it in about a week and states 'Your passport application locator number is XXXXXXXXX.'

The formatting of the number being 9 digits is the same as a passport number, so my question is, is that my actual passport number?

Comment: I doubt it. It'd be the tracking number allocated to your application when it arrives. It would be allocated long before a passport would be produced.

Comment: It comes Priority Mail. That status means it's been mailed. If you're in the continental US you'll probably get it Monday or Tuesday.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

My passport was delivered today and the passport application locator number **was not** the same as the passport number.

That said, 2 of my bookings which required my passport number (SKY Airlines and BUQUEBUS ferry ride) could not modify the passport number through their online UI and I'll have to contact their customer service to update.

Comment: Don't bother, just show them your shiny new passport at checkin.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, airlines don't need your passport data when buying the ticket. There should be an option to bypass that input.

If not, enter the locator number or all zeros, and come back later and edit it (go to the airlines web site, enter your booking code and last name, and change your passport data, change your seat, order special meals, etc - depending on your booking class; but entering passport should be always possible (of course I haven't flown *all* airlines in the world, but about forty, some from Russia, India, Peru, China, and all over western and eastern Europe and North America - it was always possible to enter / change the passport data later.

It needs to be correct when you check-in, be it online or at the counter. After that, it would be more effort to change it.